# Privilege Management

Tags: privileges

I have a weird problem. Suppose there is a 8-bit string to represent privilege of some process. I have 4 type of privileges A,B,C,D. Under each category, there might be sub privileges as well. How to represent it in just 8 bits?

Comment: Too vague. Are the privileges disjunct or can they be combined? How many of the subprivileges are there? Does having a subprivilege imply having a privilege, or vice versa? Can subprivileges have subprivileges? And most importantly, how many subprivileges are there? (Important enough to ask twice.)

Comment: yes they are disjucntive and as for the number of sub privileges, it can vary and subprivileges can have nested subprivileges

Answer (score 0):

If they are disjunct, just give each privilege its own unique ID, and hope they never grow beyond 256. Use a lookup table to know what's what, and what supercategories they have.